# Windows 7 not waking from sleep from USB keyboard through KVM

Tags: windows-7, sleep, kvm-switch

I have an IO Gear GS1204G (nice KVM) that I use to control one each of Windows 7 64bit, Ubuntu Linux, Mac, and ChromeOS computers. This KVM emulates the presence of the keyboard at all times, so it shouldn't appear to windows that a device was inserted or removed or anything.

Everything is working perfectly through this setup for the other devices. My only problem is that my keyboard/mouse won't wake the Windows 7 computer from sleep.

A USB keyboard connected directly to the windows 7 machine WILL wake it from sleep with no trouble at all.

Under the advanced power options, I've tried setting "USB selective suspend setting" to Disabled, and I've tried disabling Hybrid sleep.

The motherboard in question is "ASRock Z68 Extreme4 LGA 1155 Intel Z68 HDMI SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.0 ATX Intel Motherboard" and I haven't been able to find relevant settings in the Bios screen.

Any help or suggestions about how to debug the problem would be appreciated.